# Matplotlib doesn't save suptitle

Tags: matplotlib

Using matplotlib 1.4.3 and the following code, the figure and suptitle displays correctly, however upon saving, the suptitle is removed.

```
true_vals = [1,2,3]

f, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,5))
ax_arr = ax_arr.reshape(-1)
f.suptitle("This is my suptitle\nThis is the second line", fontsize=20, y=1.1) 
# y is set to 1.1 to keep the second line in the suptitle from hitting the top of the subplots.

for idx, i in enumerate(true_vals):
    ax_arr[idx].boxplot(data[:,idx], labels=i)

f.savefig('suptitle_test.pdf', dpi=f.dpi)
```

Answer (score 11):

[Using the advice given here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/savefig-bbox-inches-tight-does-not-consider-suptitle-tp16133p16134.html),

adding the following to the `savefig` command will produce a tight plot, keeping the suptitle in the saved figure:

```
true_vals = [1,2,3]

f, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,5))
ax_arr = ax_arr.reshape(-1)
my_suptitle = f.suptitle("This is my suptitle\nThis is the second line", fontsize=20, y=1.1) 
# y is set to 1.1 to keep the second line in the suptitle from hitting the top of the subplots.

for idx, i in enumerate(true_vals):
    ax_arr[idx].boxplot(data[:,idx], labels=i)

f.savefig('suptitle_test.pdf', dpi=f.dpi, bbox_inches='tight',bbox_extra_artists=[my_suptitle])
```

Comment: Just to stress the bbox_inches='tight' argument must be used otherwise the figure will be rendered without suptitle. See explanation in the matplotlib reference https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html